# HP DV2 1010ea Wireless card not showing networks any more

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

Two summers ago I acquired a new Laptop - an HP Pavilion DV2 1010ea. Nice form factor and stylish. However, it shipped with Vista and I could tell from day 1 it was struggling and I wanted to put Ubuntu on it anyway. At first I used 9.10 but the wireless was a nightmare. 10.04 helped the situation with an easy to obtain driver package. Recently I started over with 10.10 and was at first impressed when a driver was automatically found and installed for me. However, I turned the card off at some point to save battery and it hasn't worked since.

More accurately, turning it off and on does make a difference - an Enable/Disable wireless option will appear and disappear in the networking menu but no networks ever appear in the menu now. I've tried returning to 10.04 but the problem persists.

Unfortunately, this has essentially rendered the entire machine more or less useless as my primary use for it is for using the Wireless network at university.

The card itself is a Broadcom BCM4312 which I believe is quite common. Can anyone suggest how I might be able to test/reset or get this working again?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the driver package and reinstalling it?

Comment: Tried that and reinstalling the OS. Problem seems to be with the hardware and its own memory